# pre remove middleware not firing

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and trying to cascade a delete but unfortunately my pre remove middle ware is not firing for some reason.

```
  var presentationSchema = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    title: String,
    pdfURL: String,
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date,
    slides: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Slide'
    }]
  });

  presentationSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    console.log("delete slides" + this._id);
      next();
  });

  // the schema is useless so far
  // we need to create a model using it
  var Presentation = mongoose.model('Presentation', presentationSchema);


  // make this available to our users in our Node applications
  module.exports = Presentation;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you get hooked by [this mongoose "feature"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) :

> Note: There is no query hook for remove(), only for documents. If you
>   set a 'remove' hook, it will be fired when you call myDoc.remove(),
>   not when you call MyModel.remove(). Note: The create() function fires
>   save() hooks.

Your `pre('remove',...)` middleware will be fired when you call `myPres.remove()` not when calling remove function from the model like `Presentation.remove()`

Comment: Thanks that was exactly my issue